# Java Logic Issue in askQuestion() method

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Java math training program. I have a working version in Javascript and some of you guys have already helped me convert it over to Java. It's supposed to ask the user a difficulty (which then uses that amount of digits for each number in the questions). It then asks the user what type of math to do (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, random). It then asks the user 10 questions. As the user answers, it tells them if they're right or wrong. If wrong, they get to continue attempting the question. At the end of 10 questions, it calculates if you got over 75% of them right and displays an appropriate response. Full instructions:

[image]

I finally got most of it working correctly, only to find out that the math itself is wrong.
Sometimes if I enter a difficulty of 2, it only gives 1 digit (it basically doesn't calculate the difficulty right). Also, it always tells me my math is wrong. Is there any chance you guys can spot anything wrong with the logic?

Thanks for any help.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assignment2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int difficulty = 1;
        String[] operators = {"plus", "minus", "times", "divided by"};
        int selectedOperator = 1;
        int correctAnswers = 0;
        int answeredTyped = 0;

        int difficultyInput = Integer.parseInt(
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Please choose the difficulty. " + 
                    "Enter the number of digits to use in each problem."));

        if (difficultyInput > 0) {
            difficulty = difficultyInput;
        }
        int arithmeticMethod = Integer.parseInt(
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                "Choose an arithmetic problem to study: " +
                    "1 = Addition Only, 2 = Subtraction Only, " +
                        "3 = Multiplication Only, 4 = Division Only, " +
                            "5 = Random Problems" ));

        selectedOperator = arithmeticMethod;
        new Assignment2().askQuestion(
                difficulty, null, arithmeticMethod,
                arithmeticMethod, operators, arithmeticMethod); 
    }

    public static boolean checkResponse (
            int primaryInt, int secondaryInt,
                String operatorText, float response){
        boolean result = false;
        switch (operatorText) {
            case "1":
                return (primaryInt + secondaryInt) == response;
            case "2":
                return (primaryInt - secondaryInt) == response;
            case "3":
                return (primaryInt * secondaryInt) == response;
            case "4":
                return (primaryInt / secondaryInt) == response;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static String displayResponse (boolean isCorrect) {
        int randomIndex = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1);
        switch (randomIndex) {
            case 1:
                return isCorrect ? "Very Good!" : "No. Please try again.";
            case 2:
                return isCorrect ? "Excellent!" : "Wrong. Try once more.";
            case 3:
                return isCorrect ? "Nice Work!" : "Don\'t give up!";
            case 4:
                return isCorrect ? "Keep up the good work!" : "No. Keep trying.";
        }
        return "Oops...";
    }

    public static void askQuestion(
            int difficulty, String operatorText,
            int selectedOperator, int answeredTyped,
            String[] operators, int correctAnswers) {
        boolean correctAnswer = false;
        int primaryInt = (int) Math.floor(Math.pow(10,  difficulty-1) + Math.random() * 9 * Math.pow(10,  difficulty-1));
        int secondaryInt = (int) Math.floor(Math.pow(10,  difficulty-1) + Math.random() * 9 * Math.pow(10, difficulty-1));
        operatorText = (selectedOperator == 5) ? operators[(int) Math.floor(Math.random() * operators.length)] : operators[selectedOperator - 1];

        while(!correctAnswer && answeredTyped < 10) {
            float response = Float.parseFloat (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much is " + primaryInt + " " + operatorText + " " + secondaryInt + "?")); 
            correctAnswer = checkResponse (primaryInt, secondaryInt, operatorText, response);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, displayResponse(correctAnswer));

            answeredTyped++;

            if(correctAnswer)
            correctAnswers++;
        }
        {
            while(answeredTyped < 10) {
                askQuestion(0, null, 0, 0, null, 0);
            }
            if((correctAnswers / answeredTyped) >= 0.75) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null, "Congratulations, you are ready to " +
                    "go on to the next level!");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null, "Please ask your teacher for extra help.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you code where you are calling askQuestion you have done

```
new Assignment2().askQuestion(arithmeticMethod, null, arithmeticMethod, arithmeticMethod, operators, arithmeticMethod);
}
```

But looking at your method definition it should be, you are passing arthmeticMethod instead of difficulty level

```
new Assignment2().askQuestion(difficulty, null, arithmeticMethod, arithmeticMethod, operators, arithmeticMethod);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shivam! It looks like making that change fixed the difficulty issue, but it's still telling me the answers are wrong. Any idea on that one? I'm new to programming in general, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is because of your check response function. You are comparing 2 doubles which will never be accurate and thus, will always evaluate to false. Rule of thumb: never compare doubles if you want to condition on it, introduces unnecessary bugs. You might want to evaluate your answer to the closest int or upto 2 decimal points and then check.

Comment: Alright, I changed the doubles to integers and it still appears to be giving me a false answer... maybe I didn't change it correctly?
I have edited the original question to include my updated code. Any other ideas?
Thanks again for your help!